# If I have a Indian visa should I need transit visa

Tags: visas, transit, bangladeshi-citizens

I have a Indian tourist visa . So if I want to fly form Indian to another country I need a transit visa or not? I am from Bangladesh n I will go to Kyrgyzstan .

Comment: It depends on which country you would be transiting through, and most likely on your citizenship.  Can you edit your question to add this information?

Comment: @Sazzat For clarity, you are a Bangladeshi citizen currently in India on a tourist visa, wishing to travel from India to Kyrgyzstan, transiting via which country(ies)? For what purpose? When do you plan to leave Kyrgyzstan and/or return home? Please edit your question to provide more information (don’t just post a new question).

Answer (score 2):

Your question is still a bit unclear, but this information may be useful:

1. If you are in India with a tourist visa, and you will fly from India directly to Kyrgyzstan, you do not need a transit visa because you will not be in transit anywhere; you're just leaving India following a stay that was covered by your tourist visa.
2. If you are not in India, and you will be flying to Kyrgyzstan through India, and your transit is a "direct transit through an airport," you [do not need a visa](https://www.hcidhaka.gov.in/pages?id=eyJpdiI6IkJOSDV3NVp4b1NEQkpNMVwvVTFQQnh3PT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6IjlcL2QzdmZ2OHhteXBqN3FOT3BsbFwvZz09IiwibWFjIjoiZjRhYWQ5OTAxZTZlNWQxNWUzOThmZGMxODE3YWUwMzEyZjgxOWYyMWUxZmE5ZGNlY2Y1NjJmMDhhZTBmMjQ3NiJ9&subid=eyJpdiI6IjNKRWh5RER6WENYbUtcL1VQMFF6b0JnPT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6ImpDWmk2d2Ftc0pNYnVBdmo1ejMzRmc9PSIsIm1hYyI6ImM3Y2Y0OTc4ZWJhZjE4NWEzYzdiZWE2ZGE0MTRhZDVhZmE0ZmVhMWRiNzU3YWE1YTAyOTdhZDc1ZTlkZjVjMzYifQ==).  I do not see any formal definition of "direct transit through an airport," however.
3. If you are not in India, and you will be flying to Kyrgyzstan through India, and your transit is not a "direct transit through an airport," you may need a transit visa.  Most countries allow people who hold tourist visas to use the tourist visa for transit.  I could not find anything online that unambiguously says that India also follows this practice.
4. If you will be transiting through any country other than India, the question of whether you need a transit visa for that country depends on which country it is.